# AlertDialog, MySQL connection and Android

Tags: android, mysql, android-alertdialog

I have a question about AlertDialog in Android and MySQL connection.

In the mysql connection based in the last question. I wanna put an AlertDialog when the database is empty, or the query result empty, indicating the info. Is this possible?

There is my code (now working):

```
package net.medinfo.movil.prot2;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Busqueda2 extends Activity
{

    AutoCompleteTextView texto;
    Button boton;
    TextView resultado;
    String total;
    InputStream is = null;
    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        texto = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.cajaTexto);
        String[] meds = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arreglo_medicamentos);
        ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this, R.layout.lista_med, meds);
        texto.setAdapter(adapter);
        boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonBuscar);
        resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultado);
        boton.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener()
        {   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                //Se llama el metodo para ejecutar el recibo de datos
                resultado.setText(Medicamentos(total));

            }
        });
    }



    protected String Medicamentos (String returnString)
    {


        String txt = texto.getText().toString();
        if(!txt.equals(""))
        {
        String result ="";

        //Se envian datos de consulta;
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametros = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name" , txt));       

        //Conectando a la base de datos
        try
        {
            HttpClient cliente = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost direccion = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/medinfo/conexion.php");
            direccion.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametros));
            HttpResponse respuesta = cliente.execute(direccion);
            HttpEntity entity = respuesta.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error en la conexion a la base de datos"+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al conectar a la base de datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

            //Transformar respuesta de la conexion en string
        try
        {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String linea = null;
            if ((linea = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(linea + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error al transformar datos. "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al transformar datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        //Recibir datos en formato JSON
        try
        {
            JSONArray jArreglo = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0; i<jArreglo.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject json_datos = jArreglo.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("log_tag", "nombre: "+json_datos.getString("Nombre")+
                        ", cantidad: "+json_datos.getInt("Stock"));
                    returnString += "\n\t" + jArreglo.getJSONObject(i);
            }   
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error al recibir datos"+e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error al mostrar datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }
        else Toast.makeText(this, "Escriba un medicamento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        texto.setText("");
        return returnString;
    }
}
```

I appreciate all the help.

UPDATED: Well, now im testing the code, and i decide to put the alerdialog in the JSONexception, until now the alertdialog it works but i have some problem with a button. the button "Ampliar Busqueda" must call a method called "Alternativos" when do the sames as Medicamentos but with another query, the result must be appear in the textview "resultado", now im having a java.lang.NullException. i don't know why.

This is the code

```
package net.medinfo.movil.prot2;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Busqueda2 extends Activity
{

    AutoCompleteTextView texto;
    Button boton;
    TextView resultado;
    String total;
    String comp;
    InputStream is = null;
    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        texto = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.cajaTexto);
        String[] meds = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arreglo_medicamentos);
        ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this, R.layout.lista_med, meds);
        texto.setAdapter(adapter);
        boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonBuscar);
        resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultado);
        final AlertDialog.Builder mensaje = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        mensaje.setTitle("Oops...");

        boton.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener()
        {   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                //Se llama el metodo para ejecutar el recibo de datos
                resultado.setText(Medicamentos(total));
                while (resultado.equals(""))
                {

                    resultado.setText(total);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    protected String Medicamentos (String returnString)
    {


        String txt = texto.getText().toString();
        if(!txt.equals(""))
        {
        String result ="";

        //Se envian datos de consulta;
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametros = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name" , txt));       

        //Conectando a la base de datos
        try
        {
            HttpClient cliente = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost direccion = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/medinfo/conexion.php");
            direccion.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametros));
            HttpResponse respuesta = cliente.execute(direccion);
            HttpEntity entity = respuesta.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error en la conexion a la base de datos"+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al conectar a la base de datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

            //Transformar respuesta de la conexion en string
        try
        {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String linea = null;
            if ((linea = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(linea + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error al transformar datos. "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al transformar datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        //Recibir datos en formato JSON

        try
        {
            JSONArray jArreglo = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0; i<jArreglo.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject json_datos = jArreglo.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("log_tag", "nombre: "+json_datos.getString("Nombre")+
                        ", cantidad: "+json_datos.getInt("Stock"));
                    returnString += "\n\t" + jArreglo.getJSONObject(i); 
                    comp = json_datos.getString("componentes");
            }   
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {

                Log.e("log_tag", "Error al recibir datos"+e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error al mostrar datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                AlertDialog.Builder mensaje = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                mensaje.setTitle("Oops...");
                mensaje.setMessage("El medicamento se encuentra sin stock");
                mensaje.setPositiveButton("Ampliar Busqueda", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                    {
                        resultado.setText(Alternativos(total));
                    }
                });
                mensaje.setNegativeButton("Reintentar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                    {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                mensaje.show();
        }
        }
        else Toast.makeText(this, "Escriba un medicamento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return returnString;
    }


    protected String Alternativos (String returnString)
    {

            String result = "";
                    //Se envian datos de consulta;
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametros = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("componente" , comp.trim()));     

            //Conectando a la base de datos
            try
            {
                HttpClient cliente = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost direccion = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/medinfo/conexionalt.php");
                direccion.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametros));
                HttpResponse respuesta = cliente.execute(direccion);
                HttpEntity entity = respuesta.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error en la conexion a la base de datos"+e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error al conectar a la base de datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

                //Transformar respuesta de la conexion en string
            try
            {

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String linea = null;
                if ((linea = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(linea + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error al transformar datos. "+e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error al transformar datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            //Recibir datos en formato JSON

            try
            {
                JSONArray jArreglo = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0; i<jArreglo.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject json_datos = jArreglo.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("log_tag", "nombre: "+json_datos.getString("Nombre")+
                            ", cantidad: "+json_datos.getInt("Stock"));
                        returnString += "\n\t" + jArreglo.getJSONObject(i); 
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error al recibir datos"+e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error al mostrar datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return returnString;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE 2: The php code is:

```
<?php

      mysql_connect("localhost","root","123456");
      mysql_select_db("medinfo_movil");
      $query=mysql_query("SELECT Nombre, Componentes, Stock FROM medicamento WHERE componentes like 
      '".$_REQUEST['componente']."%' and Stock > 0");

      while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

              $output[]=$row;

           print(json_encode($output));

           mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: All your code is fine.  parametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("componente" , comp.trim())); what about this? If you send component name with space between (and in your db you have written it WITH space) your  server recieves it WITHOUT space. This might be wrong. Try it without trim()

Answer (score 0):

I can think of ways to test:
If the JSONObject is empty/null then the query returned 0-rows from your database. First of all try outputing zero-row result from your query in your php code. Write test based on these PHP results. Also you can check in the `respuesta` if the response contains result from your query.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6r1mx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wbit.610.help.config.doc/topics/rjsonnullunsempprops.html

Here there is more info about empty and null JSON objects.

Edit:

```
[{"_id":"23","imenaobjekt":"Fire Fighting Depot","lat_":"48511471","long_":"28951451","category":"0",},{"_id":"22","imenaobjekt":"Police Station????????? ???????","lat_":"4882837","long_":"285576","category":"0",}]
```

Combination of key and value.

Comment: I put the AlertDialog in the JSONException catch, and it works. Now my problem is assign the Positive Button to a procedure, (new code in the question) and display the result in a textview located in the main, but i have a java.lang.NullException. i don't know why. Please help.

Comment: Alternativos(total) is returning null, check WHY it is returning null. If this NPE occurs in particular situations do this: If(Alternativos(total)!=null){   resultado.setText(Alternativos(total)); }

Comment: Your idea it works, now i have other problem: JSONException value <br of java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray;

Comment: Well than your query returns something like empty row. Because if the query had data and probably in your php code you have echo or print(json_encode($output)) then you'll have JSON output like... see the edit above...

Comment: The JSON appears in the browser, thats odd. The query works before the AlertDialog, but in the AlertDialog the error appears.

Comment: Are you outputing(in your php) something which is not encoded with json_encode($string) or you have some HTML code? Make sure you dont have.

Comment: The php code does the print, even the json appear en the browser. Is PHP only.

Comment: I know, i know, I'm telling you to check is there some standalone echo or print, which prints something that is not encoded with json_encode()

Comment: mmm, nope. Nothing outside of json is printed